PHP form post $_POST & showing in curl
I have a little API script
I'm trying to post from a form on the same page ACTIVE or SUSPENDED.
But show text in the curl script. but its not showing $variable and just the code I put in
<?php
$variable = $_POST['name'];
echo $variable;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '....');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ...',
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{ "state": "<?php echo $variable; ?>"}');

$response = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($response);

curl_close($ch);

?>

<form method="POST" action="suspend.php">
    <input type="text" name='name' value="some value">
    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>



<?php echo doesn't work inside a string. It only works after you've exited PHP mode with ?>.
Create an array containing the variable and use json_encode().
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(["state" => $variable]));


This works perfect. but now im trying to get it working the URL one now :(

What do you mean by "the URL one"?

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, json_encode(['https://console.monogoto.io/thing/$sim/state/']));
So its the same same before getting from a post but with ID sim

A URL is not JSON.

$url = '...?state=' + urlencode($variable);

How would I do this one :(

Sorry, I'm lost now.

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do by calling json_encode() with CURLOPT_URL. I assumed you're trying to get the parameter into query parameter instead of PUT data.

I think you need to ask a new question about this.

I have asked a new question
